# Undefined _id populate with express, moongose/MongoDB on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Already have the following petition of my client, need than on one request to the database extract a document joining to other documents in one, I decided, to use function populate of MongoDB with moongose, but already im stuck in a following problem:

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQHw4.png)

models

1. models/User.js:

> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> var mongoose, Schema, UserSchema, schemaOptions, bcrypt;
> mongoose  = require('mongoose');
> bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
> Schema = mongoose.Schema;
> schemaOptions = {
>     toObject: {
>       virtuals: true
>     }
>     ,toJSON: {
>       virtuals: true
>     },
>     timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
>     new: true,
>     runValidators: true
>   };
>
> UserSchema = Schema({
>     _id:{
>       type:Number,
>       unique: true,
>       index: true
>      },
>   provider:String,
>   id:{
>           type: String
>       },
>   displayName:{
>           type: String,
>           required:  [true, 'Scribe the Full name']
>       },
>   name: {
>           familyName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the last name']},
>           givenName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the first name']},
>           middleName:{type: String,required:  [true, 'Scribe the middle name']}
>          },
>   emails:[{
>           value:{
>                 type: String,
>                 unique: true,
>                 lowercase: true,
>                 index: true,
>                 validate: {
>                  validator: function(v) {
>                    return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(v);
>                  },
>                  message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email!'}
>                 },
>         type:{
>              type: String,
>              lowercase: true
>            }
>     }],
>   email:{
>          type: String,
>          unique: true,
>          lowercase: true,
>          index: true,
>          validate: {
>           validator: function(v) {
>             return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/.test(v);
>           },
>           message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email for autenticate!'
>         },
>          required: [true, 'Scribe a Email']
>         },
>   password: {
>              type: String,
>              required: [true, 'Scribe a password']
>             },
>   photos:[{
>           type: String  
>         }],
>   alias: {
>           type: String,
>           required: [true, 'Scribe the alias'],
>           unique: true
>          },
>   birthday:{
>            type: Date,
>            required: [true, 'Select a birthday']
>            },
>   idiom: {
>          type: String,
>          required: [true, 'Select a idiom']
>          },
>   country: {
>            type: Number,
>            required: [true, 'Select a valid country'],
>            min:1,
>            max:231
>        },
>    rolId:{
>        type: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Rol' }
>    },
>   deletedAt: { type: Date, default: null }
> },schemaOptions);
>
> // Execute before each user.save() call
> UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
>   var user = this;
>
>   // Break out if the password hasn't changed
>   if (!user.isModified('password')) return callback();
>
>   // Password changed so we need to hash it
>   bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
>     if (err) return next(err);
>
>     bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
>       if (err) return next(err);
>       user.password = hash;
>       next();
>     });
>   });
> });
>
> //metodo para autenticar la clave recibida
> UserSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password, next) {
>   bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(error, isMatch) {
>     if (error) {
>         next(error);
>     };
>      next(null, isMatch);
>   });
> };
>
>
> module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
> ```
>
> 2. models/Rol.js:
>
> ```
> 'use strict';
>
> var mongoose, Schema, RolSchema, schemaOptions;
>
> mongoose  = require('mongoose');
> Schema = mongoose.Schema;
> schemaOptions = {
>     toObject: {
>       virtuals: true
>     }
>     ,toJSON: {
>       virtuals: true
>     },
>     timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
>     new: true,
>     runValidators: true
>   };
>
> RolSchema = Schema({
>   _id:{
>       type:Number,
>       unique: true,
>       index: true
>      },
>   name:{
>          type: String,
>          unique: true,
>          uppercase: true,
>          required: [true, 'Scribe a Rol']
>         },
>   deleted_at: { type: Date, default: null }
> },schemaOptions);
>
> module.exports = mongoose.model('Rol',RolSchema);
> ```

2. controllers/UserController.js:

> 'use strict'; 
>    var validator = require('validator');
>    var User = require('../models/User'); 
>    var Rol = require('../models/Rol');
>   function loggin(req, res){   console.log(req.user);   return
>   res.status(200).send({user:req.user}); }
>
> function createUser(req, res) {
>     var params , user, full_name, firstName, secondName, arrayOfName,tempUser;
>     params = req.body;
>     full_name = params.name+" "+params.last_name;
>     arrayOfName = params.name.split(" ");
>     firstName = arrayOfName[0]; 
>     secondName = arrayOfName[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQHw4.png);
>
> ```
> User.find({},function (error, users) {
>    if(error){
>     return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al devolver los marcadores del servidor'});
>    }
>    Rol.findById(params.rol,function (error, rol) {
>             if(error){
>               return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al devolver los roles del servidor'});
>             }
>             if(!rol){
>               return res.status(404).send({message: 'No hay rol creado! con el id: '+params.rol+', comuniquese con el
> ```
>
> administrador'});
>                   }
>                   if(users.length === 0){
>                   user = new User();
>                   user._id = 1;
>                   user.displayName = full_name;
>                   user.name.familyName = params.last_name;
>                   user.name.givenName = firstName;
>                   user.name.middleName = secondName;
>                   user.email = params.email;
>                   user.password = params.password;
>                   user.alias = params.username;
>                   user.birthday = params.age;
>                   user.idiom = params.idiom;
>                   user.country = params.ubication;
>                   user.rolId = rol._id;
>                   user.deleted_at = null;
>                   user.save(function (error, userStored){
>                     console.log(error);
>                     if(error){
>                       return res.status(500).send({message:"Error al guardar el usuario por primera ves"});
>                     }
>                     return res.status(200).send({user:userStored});
>                 });
>           }else{
>              tempUser = User.findOne({ 'email': params.email }, function (error, userOnDataBase) {
>                   if(error){
>                    return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al devolver los marcadores del servidor'});
>                   }
>
> ```
>             if(!userOnDataBase){
>                 user = new User({
>                   "_id":users[0]._id+1,
>                   "displayName":full_name,
>                   "name.familyName":params.last_name,
>                   "name.givenName":firstName,
>                   "name.middleName":secondName,
>                   "email":params.email,
>                   "password":params.password,
>                   "alias":params.username,
>                   "birthday":params.age,
>                   "idiom":params.idiom,
>                   "country":params.ubication,
>                   "rolId":rol._id,
>                   "deleted_at":null
>                   }).save(function (error, userStored){
>                       if(error){
>                         return res.status(500).send({message:"Error al guardar el usuario"});
>                       }
>                       return res.status(200).send({user:userStored});
>                });   
>             }else{
>               if (userOnDataBase.email === users[0].email){
>                 return res.status(409).send({message: 'Correo utilizado actualmente existe!'});   
>               }   
>             }
>         });
>      }
>    });
>
> }).limit(1).sort('-_id'); }
> ```
>
> function getUser(req, res) {
>       var id = req.params.id;
>       res.status(200).send({user_id:id}); }
>
> function updateUser(req, res) {
>       var id = req.params.id;
>       res.status(200).send({user_id:id}); }
>
> function deleteUser(req, res) {
>       var id = req.params.id;
>       res.status(200).send({user_id:id}); }
>
> module.exports = {
>       loggin, createUser, getUser, updateUser, deleteUser };

Already the collection rols have documents.

Comment: You are passing rolId as 1 , it should be object id same _id:ObjectId('string') as in Rol table

Comment: thanks for answer, nop,i did already, i tried with rol._id, and appeared the same error.

Comment: I know this is a 2 years question, but maybe someone went through a same painful search as I did. Maybe you need to call the queried doc's `toObject()` first before calling its `._id`. So, `const obj = doc.toObject();  const docId = obj._id;`